# C# Datagridview rows not updated by insert to database

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have a local database in C# and I return its content via this command :

```
    public DataTable getVillages()
    {
        try
        {
            string strCommand = "SELECT * FROM village";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(strCommand, conn);
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (SqlCeException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Source + "\n" + e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);

            return null;
        }
    }
```

and on the other side I get this datatable and assign it to my datagridview :

```
dataGridView.DataSource = villageData.getVillages();
```

but my dataGridView RowsCount is 0 and its rows not updated with database content. But I see the inserted row in dataGridView at runtime, but its rowscount is 0.

Answer (score -1):

You tried to update the DataGrid?

```
dataGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: I don't have such method

Comment: That method is for the ASP.Net DataGrid, not the winforms DataGridView